# Power Bi DAX - sum with filters

Tags: powerbi

I am a Power Bi beginner, trying to solve the following issue.

I have got the following table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfakF.png)

I would like to get this result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFevo.png)

Basically the new measure should show sums for each project forecast.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is basic functionality. If you bring a table visual and add the selected columns from your desired result it should just work. What are the results you're currently getting?

Comment: Hi @JoaoLeal , I spent a few hours trying dragging and activating/deactivating fields yet, but I did not managed to achieve the result I am aiming for.

Comment: You've not provided enough information in your question. Please share a sample data set /data model, and also the results you are currently getting.

Comment: @JoaoLeal sorry I am new also here :) .  <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/i24u6ivxgcp7wia/logcosts.xlsx?dl=0">file</a> <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/48f8me1m1mipmft/test.JPG?dl=0">file</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: PowerBI_screenshot]

To get the final table you have to choose Table on Visualizations and organize columns in this way (see the screenshot). Then right click on Forecast in Values and check Don't summarize.
If it doesn't help, please check the data types.

[image: PowerBI bar chart]

Comment: Thanks @andrew , the table works fine. However I want to have a bars chart with one bar for each prj forecast grouped per project and the best I could get is the result splitted in different charts [bar-chart](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdh4p2i7rsytofn/Capture2.JPG?dl=0). Is there any way to get the same number of bars all in one single chart ?

Comment: You can put both columns in Axis (see PowerBI bar chart image in my answer) and then use arrows in the upper right corner of the chart to drill down.